# Firebase Plain Java Client

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage

How can I integrate Firebase with a Java desktop application?

Is there a .jar file I could download?

I've seen plain Java docs on the old Firebase version but I'm unable to find any documentation on the latest version of Firebase.

My IDE is Netbeans.

Thanks.

Comment: Out of curiosity, which specific APIs within Firebase are you trying to use?

Comment: Database, authentication and storage

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I think you may be able to use the server version of the code (https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/server/start) in conjunction with the OAuth code in the Google API Client Library (https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/google-oauth-java-client/oauth2), though you may be better served by using the equivalent  functionality in Google Cloud Platform, in particular, creating an API with Google Cloud Endpoints on top of storage in Google Cloud Storage and in Google Cloud Datastore or Google Cloud SQL.

Comment: Interesting suggestion Michael, thanks! If I would elaborate more on my project it has an Android part too,I want to build a web app or desktop app using Java for an Admin panel. So to clarify If I were to go in the Java web app direction for the admin panel my options are to either use your suggested method or use the JavaScript API?

Comment: Thanks for the additional information. If it's acceptable to implement your admin panel as a web application in JavaScript, I think that you will find that to be the most well-supported approach and the path of least resistance.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion, what JS framework would you recommend I should use to develop a simple admin panel, I don't won't to get into too much complications since I'm not very familiar with JS than I'm with Java.

Comment: My personal recommendation would be Angular2, because it has very heavy backing by Google, can be rendered both server-side and client-side, allows you to compose UIs from "components" that are fully isolated from one another, and is the successor to AngularJs which has fairly widespread industry usage. However, that being said, you can really use whatever JavaScript libraries, frameworks, etc. that you want in conjunction with the Firebase JavaScript library.

Comment: Thanks Michael, you've been very helpful! :)

Comment: You're very welcome. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use firebase-server-sdk-3.0.1.jar (current version)

In Netbeans I would recommend to create Maven project and use artifact: GroupId - com.google.firebase, ArtifactId: firebase-server-sdk.

I works perfectly for me.
You can find some documentation [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/server/setup).

To initialize SDK just follow documentation: add service account (I use Owner role, I haven't tried weaker roles), download private key, and use this snippet:

```
FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
  .setServiceAccount(new FileInputStream("path/to/downloaded private key.json"))
  .setDatabaseUrl("https://your database name.firebaseio.com/")
  .build();
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Which APIs did you get the chance to work with? My main requirements are the database, authentication and storage ,will I be able to use these APIs in this method?

Do you mind posting some sample code on how you initialized your app  because after adding the Maven dependency I'm unable to setup a connection.

Comment: I use database API, but I believe that other APIs are also supported.

Comment: Using service account is probably not the right thing to do in this scenario... not only would you provide each user with the credentials of the service account (which should generally be kept more limited), but in effect all actions would be performed as if the service account is the logged-in user (rather than acting with the authority of the human user). While a service account makes sense on a server (which is why it was used in the server example code), if reusing the server Java code on a client, this is probably not the right way to authenticate.

Comment: As Michael has said, the server SDK uses a Google service account and would not be appropriate for a desktop client as you'll have to distribute that along with the client

Comment: @MichaelAaronSafyan Is there any good alternative? I want to use Firebase (Analytics&remote-config) in an SDK I'm making...

Answer (score 2):

According to the [documentation website](https://firebase.google.com/docs/) Firebase will not work just like that, it's an application designed to run only on 3 platforms, namely:

- Android
- iOS
- Web

You can try and use the maven repository for the integration purpose, with any build script. I'm not exactly sure what you expect to do.

Comment: I wanted to integrate Firebase with a  Java desktop app or Java web app, So if I want to Integrate Firebase with a Java web app I should use the JS API?

Comment: you can use anything supported by the platform

Answer (score 2):

For Firebase Storage on the server, I recommend using [gcloud-java](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gcloud-java):

```
// Authenticate using a service account
Storage storage = StorageOptions.builder()
    .authCredentials(AuthCredentials.createForJson(new FileInputStream("/path/to/my/key.json"))
    .build()
    .service();

// Create blob
BlobId blobId = BlobId.of("bucket", "blob_name");
// Add metadata to the blob
BlobInfo blobInfo = BlobInfo.builder(blobId).contentType("text/plain").build();
// Upload blob to GCS (same as Firebase Storage)
Blob blob = storage.create(blobInfo, "Hello, Cloud Storage!".getBytes(UTF_8));
```