# How to upload files from JAVA server to Firebase Storage by any means necessary

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, java-server

I can't find how to "Upload files from JAVA server to Firebase Storage?".

I need to add a PDF file to the storage and then Push the download URL of that file to my Fireabse Database.

I can't use gcloud.
there must be a way!

Any sort of help will be apriciated.
tnx

Comment: There is no Java client for Firebase Storage. But you can use gcloud. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39060938/firebase-plain-java-client/39092855#39092855

Comment: will try thanks for ypur help